# How to get Bing Map Session Key from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, bing-maps, bing-api

To reduce the billable transaction in my web form asp.net project, i decided to test it.

I have come across following example on msdn for session key.

```
Map.CredentialsProvider.GetCredentials(
    Function(c)
        Dim sessionKey As String = c.ApplicationId
        'Generate a request URL for the Bing Maps REST services.
        'Use the session key in the request as the Bing Maps key
       Return 0
    End Function)
```

**My Code example**

```
private String GeocodeAddress(string address)
{    string results = "";

string key = "Bing Maps key";
GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest();

// Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
geocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

// Set the full address query
geocodeRequest.Query = address;

// Set the options to only return high confidence results 
ConfidenceFilter[] filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter();
filters[0].MinimumConfidence = GeocodeService.Confidence.High;

// Add the filters to the options
GeocodeOptions geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions();
geocodeOptions.Filters = filters;
geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

// Make the geocode request
GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient();
GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(geocodeRequest);

if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
    results = String.Format("Latitude: {0}\nLongitude: {1}", 
      geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude, 
      geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude);
else
    results = "No Results Found";

return results;
```

}

After debugging it, i can't see any difference b/w (application id / session key) and Bing Api key. How can i get sessionkey in above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session key can only be used on the same page as the interactive map. Passing a session key between pages is not allowed. Assuming that you have an AJAX button or something that is processing some code on the server and returning it to the same page as the map, then this would be alright.

The first bit of code looks like you are trying to generate a session key in .NET. This would only be possible if you where using Silverlight or WPF. I'll assume you are not using the Bing Maps WPF control on the server as that's really against the terms of use. If you are using Silverlight, then there is no need to pass a key to the server side.

So lets assuming you generate a key in JavaScript from the Bing Maps v7 control and pass it to AJAX button handler on the server. If this is the case then it's alright.

In your code it looks like you are using the really old legacy SOAP services which is not recommended. In fact I stopped recommending them about 4 or 5 years ago. The documentation was taken offline a couple of years ago. You should be using the Bing Maps REST services which are faster, more accurate and has more features. You can find documentation on how to use them in .NET here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

Also, here are some tips on using the REST services: http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-tricks/

ApplicationId and session key are the same thing. The SOAP services are so old it used to have a different name.

You won't see any differences in the reports right away. It can take up to a week for the reports to sync up across all the servers/data centers as it's a low priority job with massive amounts of data.

If your application has decent traffic you will likely end up with a lot more non-billable transactions than billable transactions which will likely cause your account to be flagged and investigated and possibly blocked.

What you should be doing is geocoding your addresses ahead of time and storing the coordinates. This is how most applications handle this type of scenario. The only time you should need to geocode on the fly is if you have a search box for user input, all everything else should be geocoded ahead of time for performance.

Comment: I am trying to implement Bing Map on my asp.net web form application. I am trying to figure out how to get the session key from code behind the page. I can do with java script but from code behind i don't know if it is possible. 

I have a generic list of engineers which contains addresses including Lat and Lng values. Is it possible to loop through the list and calculated travel distance from given lat and lng before displaying them on the repeater control (just showing distance values) using one session key.

Comment: If you have a Known User (or light Known user) then sessions won't change anything in terms of cost. With a known user license you pay for the number of users who have access to the app and not the number of transactions that are created.

Comment: This is interesting, guy who is selling license to us mentioned that it doesn't matter that how many user license you buy 1 or 300, transaction limit applies to all of them not on individual user. So for an example if daily limit is 25k then it is not 300 x 25k instead 25k is a whole limit which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: For a small number of users, less than 5000, the maximum number of transactions for a known user account stays the same. After 5000 users it then increases. Note that the daily limit is the most transactions that can be done in a day, not the most transactions you can do everyday. There is a yearly limit as well which is the cap. The idea is to prevent someone from using a years worth of transactions in a single day.

Comment: sorry i am confused, does session key matters for Light Known Users? I am not talking about cost, i am looking at reducing billable transactions. If we buy light user license then it is still a good idea to use session key as there is still a daily or annual transaction limit.

Comment: Session keys won't make a difference to these limits if using a known user license.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63171/discussion-between-user1263981-and-rbrundritt).